# Pod install won't install the pods

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I'm having an issue when running the pod install.

This is how my pod file looks like:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Template1' do


pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"

end
```

But it won't install the pods,once i execute *pod install* , this is the output it gives.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Template1.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total
pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: quit xcode and run pod install again..

Comment: @M.K. i did that, but same result.

Comment: remove ', :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"' this part and try again

Comment: Please check my answer and back to me...

Comment: @SathiReddy same result

Comment: Did u enter it in Podfile

Comment: @posha Please check my edit....

Answer (score 7):

1. Delete "Pods" directory from your project directory(if exist)
2. In terminal, $open -a xcode Podfile
3. Use this: (Podfile)

   platform :ios, '8.0'

   target 'Template1' do

   pod “PinterestSDK”

   end
4. In terminal, $ cd YOUR_PROJECT_PATH
5. pod install

Comment: HI, i sought out that issue. Thanks. It was an issue with the path.

Comment: Please mark my answer with tick, if it helped you...Others can get benefit from it..

Comment: Hi @KSR, didn't understand your answer, could you explain?

Answer (score 2):

After running the command pod install you'll get a message shown in the given image. After that just delete the Podfile and run your project it will automatically create another Podfile and will generate dependencies included in pub spec.yaml[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AFqH.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React Native, make sure to add this on top of your pod file.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods' 
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules' 
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error occurred when I running the `flutter` application on macOS.

I deleted `macos/podfile` , `macos/podfile.lock` file and re-ran `flutter run`, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your pod file is almost empty like below example.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Runner' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Runner

end
```

There should be some necessary information. You can copy it from other project. Or you can use from this link.
https://learnflutter.co/flutter-podfile-0-dependencies/

I found this answer from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s2JTEzHrlA

Comment: But we already know that the OPs podfile doesn't look like that. And besides the problem is solved already.